# Want to delete any unique userid has more than 50 items

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with named "user-recent-activity" which has following columns: id, userid, activity and datetime. Now, I want to delete the records if any unique userid has more than 50 items, deleting the oldest records. For example, if the user id(lets say 1234) has more than 50 records in this table, then I have to save latest 50 records of user id(1234)  and delete the oldest one.

Answer (score 3):

Before inserting, query for the last 50 records with that ID (ordering from newer to older). If there *is* a 50th, substitute it (via update) instead of inserting a new row.

Comment: +1, like ur answer, but is there any way to delete the records from database?

Comment: why delete when you can reuse? (you can replace the "substitute" operation by a delete and an insert, but why no do both with a single update?).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a RDBMS that supports standard SQL the following stored procedure should do it.

create procedure remove-old-activities
(
@userid int
)
as
delete from user-recent-activity where userid=@userid and id not in (select top 50 id from user-recent-activity where userid=@userid order by datetime desc)

If you're DB does not support stored procedures then you should be able to use SQL parameters to pass the userid value...

Hope that helps

Comment: Just call this stored procedure after any operation that writes to the user-recent-activity table or better still have it called by an insert trigger attached to the same table.

Comment: in your case, I have to pass the user id in procedure call. For user id, I have to call another select query.

Comment: indeed you do however that list is easily generated and you can use a cursor over that list passing each to the stored proc (or executing directly): SELECT userid FROM user-recent-activity GROUP BY userid HAVING COUNT(userid) > 50

Answer (score 0):

You could use rank method to precisely defined the rows number and thus delete the rows you want.

```
 delete from tblName where id=
        (select id from (       
            select @i := CASE WHEN ( @userid <> userid ) THEN 1                      
                ELSE  @i+1                                      
                END AS rank , id,userid, datetime2 ,@userid:=userid AS clset          
            from tblName x,(SELECT @i:=0) a ,(SELECT @userid:= 0) s 
            order by x.userid, datetime2 desc) T 
          where T.rank='50')    ;
```

Another option:
Use the select query to select the rank <=50 and insert into a new table. Delete the old table and rename the new table afterwards.

```
insert into newtable (userid,activity,datetime2)
select userid,datetime2 from (
      select @i := CASE WHEN ( @userid <> userid ) THEN 1 
                    ELSE 
                     @i+1                     
                END AS rank , userid, activity,datetime2 ,@userid:=userid AS clset 
       from tblName x,(SELECT @i:=0) a ,(SELECT @userid:= 0) s
       order by x.userid, datetime2 desc) T
where t.rank <=50
```

Comment: userid is not hardcoded, there are thousands of userids in the table and I want to delete the records via cron job.

Comment: it gives me the error: "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: Pls use the second option then.

Comment: I am confused about the second option, isn't a very lengthy procedure to delete the entries :(

Comment: The second option is for a one-time-work. That is select all the entries with rank <=50 into a new table (all the result you want). You could delete the old table or rename it. Then rename the new table to the table name desired. This is indeedly useful when you have multiple records to delete and also faster than find/delete one by one.